# what happens if float,double or even char value is passed in malloc

Tags: c, malloc

While studying in detail about malloc() I came across this strange behavior.

```
int *p;
p=(int*)malloc(10.45);
p=(int*)malloc(10.45f);
p=(int*)malloc('j');
```

The program compiles with any of these statements with just a warning and returns a valid address.
What's the real result here?

Comment: hail to strongly statically typed languages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of those values are implicitly converted to `size_t` before calling the function, just as if you had an explicit cast.  The floating point numbers are truncated, and the `'j'` is interpreted as its numerical value in your character set.

Answer (score 3):

"Just a warning" probably hides the explanation.

Various rules for converting/promoting values of non-integer types to integer kick in, making sure `malloc()` gets a single `size_t`, i.e. an unsigned integer. The floating point calls will probably just drop the fractions for instance, and attempt to allocate 10 bytes.

Also, [please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 3):

`malloc()` takes a size_t argument.

The compiler will truncate `10.45`/`10.45f` to `10` and convert `'j'` to its ASCII value (`106`).

It's an implicit cast to `size_t`

Comment: No, it's rather an implicit conversion. A cast, by definition, is explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Malloc is defined to accept an integer 'number of bytes'.

The C language defines the rules for converting from other data types to integers.

I'm sure you can work out for yourself what each value converts to.